# "System is exactly singular" error in R when running factanal on dataset

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am trying to conduct factor analysis in R on a dataset consisting of 129 observations and 6 variables. The observations in question are the result of survey data which used Likert scales. I converted the characters to numerics and used them to produce a scree plot without any problems.
The issue came when I then tried to use factanal on the same dataset, which produced the followign:

```
Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
> CFA <- factanal(na.omit(NDF), 3, rotation="varimax")
Error in solve.default(cv) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0
```

I then tried to construct a matrix to see if I could identitfy where the error was, which produced these results:

```
     [,1]       
[1,] Numeric,129
[2,] Numeric,129
[3,] Numeric,129
[4,] Numeric,129
[5,] Numeric,129
[6,] Numeric,129
```

This didn't help, obviously. Is there a way of figuring out where in the dataset is producing the error and is there anyway of solving it?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a small dataset that reproduces the problem? Also, the matrix is incorrectly set up. Each element seems to be a numeric vector in and of itself. Can you provide a bit more of the code?

Comment: Show all of your code, not just the lines that produced errors. We can't tell what NDF is or how many rows are left after you removed missing values. Try `cor(na.omit(NDF))`. If one of your variables is perfectly correlated with others, that can make the matrix singular.

Comment: In trying to reproduce the error I discovered that I somehow changed the dataset to a list rather than a data frame (I'm not entirely sure how this happened); by returning it to a dataframe and removing NAs I solved the problem. I'm not 100% sure why this happened, but there's a happy ending here I suppose.